# Restriction of a multivariate function

Tags: functions

What mathematical notation is most appropriate for restricting (or describing) the domain of a multivariate function? Suppose I want to restrict the domain of $f(x,y)$ so that $x$ is a real number from $10$ to $20$ and $y$ is an integer number from $-1$ to $10$. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: For $D=[10,20]\times [-1,10]$, you can use $f|_D$.

Comment: @Levent That won't say which variable belongs to the set of real numbers and which to the set of integers.

Comment: So put $D = [10, 20] \times \{-1, 0, \ldots, 10\}$ and then do as Levent suggests.

Answer (score 0):

For merely **describing** the working domain of a function $f(x,y)$, maybe:

$\text{dom}f=\{x,y\vert x\in \mathbb{R}\wedge[10,20],y\in \mathbb{Z}\wedge y\in[-1,10] \}$

or, perhaps, more precisely:

$\text{dom}f=\{x\vert x\in \mathbb{R}\wedge[10,20]\}*\{y\vert y\in \mathbb{Z}\wedge y\in[-1,10]\}$

For intentionally **restricting** the domain, maybe...

$f\vert _D$ where $D=\{x\vert x\in \mathbb{R}\wedge[10,20]\}*\{y\vert y\in \mathbb{Z}\wedge y\in[-1,10]\}$

If others upvote my answer, I'm assuming it didn't miss the mark and I will accept it. Otherwise, please offer any corrections.